# Tune the track length of a segment but not the entire net in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

I have a differential pair routed like this:

U1 ======> U2 ========> U3

I want to equal the length of the pair between U1 and U2, but Altium always try to equal the entire net length between U1 and U3.

Are there any method to achieve this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I'm doing a DDR3 routing in the fly-by style. U1 is the MCU, U2 and U3 are two DDR3 memory chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could place a net tie in your schematic either between U1 and U2 and place this net tie at the end of trace you want to do the length matching on.
When using a net tie both of the signals on either side gets their own net name even though they should be connected.

I haven't tried this myself yet, but give it a read.

> This is achieved by connecting the 2 nets through a Net Tie component. A Net Tie component is nothing more than a controlled short circuit. On the schematic, the Net Tie component has two (or more) pins, with each pin connected to the nets to be shorted. Note that the pins are not wired to each other on the schematic, but they are connected together within the PCB footprint.

[Altium description](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.1/display/ADES/((Creating+Connectivity))_AD#!CreatingConnectivity-IntentionallyConnectingTwoNets)